# Parse json string with double quotes in jquery

Tags: jquery, dust.js

I'm using dustjs and want to combine multiple templates.

When i do `{name|js}` from tutorial site ([here](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial)) i get something like `"title": "Testtitle"`. What i need is something like `title: "Testtitle"`. I also try `{name|jp}` where a String is parsed to Json Object but this doesn't worked to me.

Can i do something in jQuery to manage this?
I already tried `jsonParse` with the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &` and `eval` (same error).

Edit:

`{&quot;id&quot;:1,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Test&quot;` - this is the output in log from `{name|js}`

Comment: `title: "Testtitle"` isn't valid JSON. In JSON, all property names have to be in quotes. The quotes aren't required in Javascript literals if the property name is a valid identifier, but JSON needs them.

Comment: When i try `var your_json = {firstName:'James', lastName:'Smith'};` it works to me. But how can i parse `"{"firstName":'James',"lastName":'Smith'}"` to this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript object literals, quoting the property name is optional if it's a valid identifier. So you can write either:

```
var your_json = { firstName: 'James', lastName: 'Smith' };
```

or

```
var your_json = { "firstName": "James", lastName: "Smith" };
```

In JSON, double quotes are required. The equivalent JSON string would be:

```
var your_json_string = '{"firstName": "James", "lastName": "Smith"}';
```

or:

```
var your_json_string = "{\"firstName\": \"James\", \"lastName\": \"Smith\"}";
```

You can then parse this with:

```
var your_json = $.parseJSON(your_json_string);
```

Comment: I already tried but i got this error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token &`

Comment: There's no `&` in my code, I don't see how you would get that. Please update your question with what you're actually doing.

Comment: I did. It returns me `&quot`. Thats the problem or?

Comment: That's an HTML entity. They should only be used in HTML source code, not generated by a function.

Comment: But they are generated through `{name|js}` in dust.js :/

Comment: I finally solved it after 3 hours :) With your solution i detect the `&quot` in `console.log`. One more reason to use `console.log` instead of output it simply in html. The solution is that i do `var name = {name|js}`, then i replace all `&quot;` through `"` with `var test = name.replace(/\&quot;/g, '"');` and finally i do the `$.parseJSON`-Part